Bigquery can't not select parquet data on GCS by external table which have date value "0001-01-01"
When I select this parquet data from gcs via biquery, it raises the below error. And the min value of the column 'SETUP_DATE' is "0001-01-01".
Invalid value: Error while reading table: dataset1.table1, 
error message: Invalid date value -719164; in column 'SETUP_DATE'
File: gs://bucket01/landing/OBS/table1/XTRTS_DATE=2024-05-24/part-00001-28cdecdb-390e-48cc-9ae7-2bc785c33434.c000.snappy.parquet at [2:1]

Does any one have any solution to fix this without change any data.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

The error suggests that the SETUP_DATE column is corrupted. It will be difficult to handle without changing the data. You can try case statements or where clauses to avoid reading '-719164' and parse the dates.

This is typically caused because of ambiguity of dates in parquet prior to 1582 where Gregorian calendar replaced the Julien calendar.  BigQuery uses proleptic Gregorian calendar and typically this can be configured for newer writers of parquet.
